# The second smallest eigenvalue of a complete binary tree

Tags: spectral-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Apparently it is true that the second smallest eigenvalue of a complete binary tree is $\theta(\frac{1}{n})$. Can someone point out a reference which proves this?

Answer (score 1):

In Stephen Guattery and Gary L. Miller. On the Performance of Spectral Graph Partitioning Methods. CS CMU-CS-94-228 (Carnegie Mellon University Tech Report), this result is proved as Lemma 3.8.